# Game UI Xml Deserializer

Tags: c#, xml, user-interface, xmlserializer

the second day I'm trying to solve my problem and I think I need some help to do it. =/

So, I'm trying to do a UI for my project that for each Stage (or screen, however you name it) will take an XML and build Objects from it.

Basically, my code looks like that:

Basic class for stage's - all the other are inheriting from this one:

```
class BaseStage {
    [XmlIgnore]
    public Type Type;
    [XmlIgnore]
    public string XmlPath;
    public BaseChildren UIScheme;

    public BaseStage()
    {
        Type = GetType();
        XmlPath = "Template/" + Type.ToString().Replace("Some.Project.Namespace.", "") + ".xml";
    }

    public virtual void LoadContent()
    {
        if (File.Exists(XmlPath))
        {
            using (TextReader reader = new StreamReader(XmlPath))
            {
                XmlSerializer uiDeserializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(BaseChildren));
                UIScheme = (BaseChildren)uiDeserializer.Deserialize(reader);
            }
        }
    }
```

Some UI Classes:

```
public class BaseChildren
{
    public List<BaseChildren> Children = new List<BaseChildren>();

    public virtual void AddChild(BaseChildrenchild)
    {
        Children.Add(child);
    }
}

public class Dialog : BaseChildren {
    public string Type;
    public Rectangle Position;
}
public class Label : BaseChildren {}
// ... and so on
```

My XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<UIScheme>
  <Children>
    <Dialog>
      <Type>Blue</Type>
      <Position>
        <X>43</X>
        <Y>100</Y>
        <Width>350</Width>
        <Height>200</Height>
      </Position>
    </Dialog>
  </Children>
</UIScheme>
```

I've tried numerous variations and have no idea how to force serializer to load those objects =/
I also tried to override XmlSerializer and tried to write my own reading function, but it's hard to even get any tutorials how to properly do it in Google.

Comment: Well, your root-object in xml is `UIScheme`, while in your class-hierarchy it´s `BaseStage`.

Comment: Is your problem that you don't know in advance which subclass of `BaseStage` was serialized into the file, and so don't know in advance which type to pass to the `XmlSerializer`?  Because as @HimBromBeere noted the root XML element does not correspond to `BaseStage` it corresponds to something completely different called `UIScheme`.

Answer (score 0):

for fast check ,you can convert xml to C# class using this one http://xmltocsharp.azurewebsites.net/

```
[XmlRoot(ElementName="Position")]
public class Position {
    [XmlElement(ElementName="X")]
    public string X { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName="Y")]
    public string Y { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName="Width")]
    public string Width { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName="Height")]
    public string Height { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName="Dialog")]
public class Dialog {
    [XmlElement(ElementName="Type")]
    public string Type { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName="Position")]
    public Position Position { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName="Children")]
public class Children {
    [XmlElement(ElementName="Dialog")]
    public Dialog Dialog { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName="UIScheme")]
public class UIScheme {
    [XmlElement(ElementName="Children")]
    public Children Children { get; set; }
}
```